# Proof of the Reverse Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Here there is my proof (quite short and easy) of a rather straightforward result. The text of this question comes from a previous question of mine, where I ended up working on a wrong inequality. Here things are fixed.

Still, I would like to know:

1. if it is sound, because absolute value always creates me some problem, and
2. if there is a shorter (neater) way to get the result (maybe without using contradiction).

---

> **Proposition:** $|d(x,y)-d(y,z)| \leq d(x,z)$.
>
> *Proof:*
> We proceed by cases.
>
> - Case 1: $d(x,y)-d(y,z) \geq 0$.
>   Assume by contradiction that $d(x,y)-d(y,z) > d(x,z)$. Hence, $d(x,y)> d(y,z) + d(x,z)$, contradicting the triangle inequality.
> - Case 2: $d(x,y)-d(y,z) < 0$.
>   Assume by contradiction that $ - d(x,y) + d(y,z) > d(x,z)$. Hence, $d(x,y) < d(y,z) - d(x,z)$. By applying the triangle inequality, we have that $d(y,x) \geq d(y,z) + d(x,z)$, which is by symmetry equivalent to  $d(x,y) \geq d(y,z) + d(x,z)$, obtaining the desired contradiction. $\square$

---

As always, any feedback is welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: this is not reverse triangle inequality...http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/equations/proof.html

Comment: This is the reverse triangle inequality for general metrics.  It's OK.  See [reverse triangle inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality).

Comment: It is. Your link is to a subcase of the special case where $d$ is a norm and $y = 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your work seems right (although you could get the easier contradiction in the second case by adding $d(x,y)$), but there is an easier proof:  Let $x,y,z$ be points in a metric space.  Then

$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y).$$

Then,

$$d(x,y)-d(y,z)\leq d(x,z).$$

On the other hand,

$$d(y,z)\leq d(x,z)+d(x,y).$$

Then,

$$d(y,z)-d(x,y)\leq d(x,z).$$

Therefore,

$$|d(y,z)-d(x,y)|\leq d(x,z).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the alternative proof (and the feedback on my proof).

Comment: How do get the line after saying " On the other hand"? Im relly troubled understanding this. Thanks @MichaelBurr

Comment: It's the same as the first line, but the $x$, $y$, and $z$ are moved around.  It's the triangle inequality, the distance from $y$ to $z$ is at most the distance from $y$ to $z$ via $x$. @Cos

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to prove it by contradiction:

By the triangle inequality, $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,z)+d(y,z)$, whence
$$d(x,y)-d(y,z)\le d(x,z.)$$
Similarly, $d(y,z)\le d(y,x)+d(x,z)$, whence
$$d(y,z)-d(x,y)\le d(x,z),$$
and finally
$$\bigl\lvert d(x,y)-d(y,z)\bigr\rvert=\max\bigl(d(x,y)-d(y,z),d(y,z)-d(x,y)\bigr)\le d(x,z).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually, I don't really see the need to add the last line with the max operator.

Comment: Well, I just used explicitly one of the definitions of $\lvert a\rvert$: $\max(a,-a)$, to be sure to be clear. It all depends on the math level at which one wants to explain.